# Solve equation to find divisor that gives remainder of zero

Tags: r, division, solver

I'm trying to solve the following equation in R for x:

```
(z + x)/y = remainder of zero
```

In other words, I'm trying to find what value should be added to my number "z" so that it divided by "y" gives a remainder of zero. I couldn't find anything about it so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you want the modulus operator `%%`. When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: `y <- 7;
z <- 3;
remainder <- 0;
x <- 1:100;
x[(z+x)%%y == remainder]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are referring to a "remainder", I assume you are only dealing with integers.

```
z <- 8
y <- 7

(x <- ceiling(z / y) * y - z)
#[1] 6

(z + x) %% y
#[1] 0
```

Comment: Or maybe `x <- y-(z%%y)`?

Answer (score -1):

It's not the most optimised way but you can do this :

```
X,Y in R*
X*Y = S
S-X = Z
```

With this exept mistake from me your equation will alway give a remainder of zero